# How to know whether or not my Q9550 has TDP of 65W?

Tags: cpu

Intel has two version of the Q9550 cpu, one of them is a 95W and the other is a 65W. But I didn't find anywhere on how to tell whether you have one or the other.

Is there anywhere to check for that?

(I use Arch Linux, if that matters.)

Comment: If your processor shows up in your BIOS as a Q9550, it's a Q9550.  The Q9550S will show up with the `S` appended to the name.

Comment: @Breakthrough: I see. Thanks. I guess I have the 95W version. :-(

Comment: This information is also on the CPU itself.